# How to get model properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have model:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  itemId: DS.attr('string'),
  itemName: DS.attr('string'),
  itemType: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

I successfully create some items from JSON. I can put them to page by {{#each items}}{{ itemName}}{{/each}}. But I don't know, how to get itemName in javascript.

I tried this:

```
var item = App.Item.find(1);
console.log(item.itemName);
```

--> undefined

I can't find anything useful from emberjs and ember-data docs. Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try item.get('itemName')

Comment: yes, now :) --> undefined

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this:

```
var item = App.Item.find(1);
console.log(item.itemName);
--> undefined
```

This is normal because the call to `.find(1);` is asyncronous and returns a promise and not the item you are expecting.

Therefore you should try:

```
App.Item.find(1).then(function(result) {
  console.log(record.get('itemName'));
});
```

It also depends from where you are doing `App.Item.find()` if it's from inside a route you should wait until the `afterModel` hook is called to access your items:

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Item.find(1);
  },
  afterModel: function(record) {
    console.log(record.get('itemName'));
  }
});
```

Also be aware that if you where calling `find()` without parameter then you will receive a `RecordArray` which you need to loop over to get access to your items. Also worth mentioning is that in ember you should always use `.get()` and `.set()` instead of the vanilla dot-notation otherwise you hijack the binding mecanism resulting in no updates in your view etc.

> Note, if you are using the latest ember.js release (1.0.0) then the call to `.find()` should be made somewhat different. But that's not clear from your question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess you should also add an explanation, that he should use `.get()` and `.set()`, when he is accessing properties.

Comment: I'm using 1.0.0.-rc.7. And now my result is "Extract requested, but no data given for App.Device. This may cause weird problems."

Comment: @Meph- lamentably from the little code you have posted it's not that easy to guess where else there could be a mistake... can you provide a simple jsbin with just the distilled use case?